# OverflowMonthly

Tags: app, questions, ruby

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

OverflowMonthly is a monthly collection of the most popular questions on the Stack Exchange Network,published as ebooks(pdf and kindle format).
People can now also read the best questions on their ereaders.

#### License

http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/

#### Download

Get the book here

http://www.overflowmonthly.com

#### Platform

The ebook is currently available in pdf and mobi/kindle formats

### Contact

Please send an email to gauravtiwari5050@gmail.com

### Code

The scripts to access the API are in ruby and PDF rendering has been done using QtWebkit